# find docs where field a=value x or field b = value x in firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, angularfire2

I'm developing a chat application with firebase firestore. A chat document has the following structure

```
   {
   chatid: "FZSIPMuxxxGDuOZxxx",
   uid: "D9CPxxxxfMfMRLxxxxxxENiso2", --> /*sender_id*/
   receipient: "gsKQxxxxcJfiyxxxxxC7frDD9y1",   --> /*recipient_id*/
   count: 0, 
   messages: Array(n), --->/*messages*/
   …}
```

Provided I have a variable user_id.  I want my query to find documents where either uid==user_id or recipient==user_id

my code is at the moment is

```
db.collection("chats").where("uid", "==", user_id).where("receipient","==", user_id); 

But I dont get the any results.
Most examples I have seen check the same field against two values. like uid==1 or uid==2

But I am looking to compare the user_id against uid or recipient. Thank You!
```

Answer (score 4):

Combining those 'where' methods will result in a logical 'AND' not an 'OR' as you seem to look for.

According to firebase there is only a logical 'OR' if you are digging in an array-field, but not for several fields as you want it:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any

I had the same problem and ended up like making a firebase-function (considering some rules might not work in frontend) doing something like:

```
let user_uid = "xxx"
let myChats = []
db.collection("chats")
  .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      if (doc.data().recipient_id == user_uid || doc.data().uid == user_uid) {
        myChats.push(doc.data())
      }
    })
    console.log(myChats)
    // ...
  })
```

But the problem here is, that it will load more documents than you will need in the end so you should consider the quota usage in firebase..

//edit: had a mistake in the function..

//edit2:

Here another option where you don't fetch the whole collection, but only the docs for the user_id and recipient_id.. so only those can get double-fetched if the uid is the same in both fields:

```
let fetchChats = async user_id => {
  let dbRef = db.collection("chats")
  let response1 = await dbRef.where('uid', '==', user_id).get()
  let response2 = await dbRef.where('recipient_id', '==', user_id).get()
  let arr1 = response1.docChanges().map(element => element.doc.data())
  let arr2 = response2.docChanges().map(element => element.doc.data())
  let allChats = [...arr1, ...arr2]
  // make array unique by converting to an object
  let myChatsObj = {}
  allChats.forEach(item => { myChatsObj[item.chatid] = item })
  let myChats = Object.values(myChatsObj)
  return myChats
}
```

Comment: tried this code but it didn't work. looks like you made some typo in there can you check it up please?

Comment: the first or the second code? what does the error say?

Comment: don't forget to define: ```let db = admin.firestore()```
and please note, that the function returns a Promise, so you have to async/await it:
  ```(async () => {let chats = await fetchChats('xxx');console.log(chats);})()```